# Constructing a sequence with subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty $ such that for every real number L, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty $  with $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{n_k}=L$

I don't really know how to start. So any hints would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Let $\{x_n: x_n\in \Bbb Q\}$. Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, it is definable. And as we know:

> For any real number $L$, there exists a sequence of $\Bbb Q$ which converges to $L$.

Comment: Beware in using this hint that you'll need to ensure the indices in your subsequences actually increase.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take any enumeration $x_i$ of all rational numbers. For every real number $L$, let $y_i$ be some rational sequence converging to $L$. Pick $n_1$ so that $x_{n_1} = y_1$. Among the elements $x_1,\ldots,x_{n_1-1}$ there are at most finitely many $y_i$'s, so in particular you can find $n_2 > n_1,m_2 > 1$ such that  $x_{n_2} = y_{m_2}$. Continue in this fashion.